# Why Quantum correlation is not uniform in this diagram?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

Following diagram is from a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) which shows [Quantum Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_correlation) for [local hidden variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_hidden_variables) and Quantum Mechanics and experiments confirm Quantum Mechanics predictions.

[image]

My question is why the curve at left side (0-180 degree) is not symmetric with the curve on right side (180-360 degree) although on each side the curve is symmetric with horizontal line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of sloppy drawing. The curve should be symmetric.

Solution: pay graphic artists more! :D

Comment: Wondering how cosine could be asymmetric or I'm missing something about Bell's theorem.